Не отображаются пользовательские метки на карте Yandex MapKit
Написал код добавления пользовательской метки на карту. Она не отображается, хотя никаких ошибок нет. В чем может быть проблема?
Репозиторий с проектом

Вы используете слишком большой размер метки на карте. Если её заменить на метку нормального размера, всё будет работать корректно.
Прикладываю вам наглядные скриншоты.
https://disk.yandex.ru/i/k-hYqppsdKf-DQ
https://disk.yandex.ru/i/8zODGwavNMPlqQ
https://disk.yandex.ru/i/QW-cIxTGRXhtXA
